# Skip space after optional argument

Tags: macros, white-space

I have a command where the first argument is optional:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\newcommand{\z}[2][]{\texttt{\underline{#1} #2}}

\begin{document} \noindent
  \z[First]{Second}\\
  \z{Only}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a way to avoid the space between `#1` and `#2` when `#1` isn't specified so that it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Please, don't use `minimal` for examples; it's not intended for this usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand\z{o m }{\texttt{\IfNoValueF{#1}{\underline{#1} }#2}}

\begin{document} \noindent
  \z[First]{Second}\\
  \z{Only}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What's the difference between `\newcommand` and `\NewDocumentCommand`?

Comment: \NewDocumentCommand (provided by the xparse package) has as you can see extended possibilities to define commands.

Answer (score 3):

With `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\z}[2][]{\texttt{\ifblank{#1}{#2}{\underline{#1} #2}}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\z[First]{Second}\\
\z{Only}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The space should go before `#2`, not after it.

Comment: @egreg: Yes, I messed up copying the code of another attempt. 'Tis fixed. Thanks for pointing it!