# Omit punctuation after optional argument in glossary

Tags: macros, glossaries, optional-arguments

I'm building a glossary of German Mathematics terms. I would like to omit the comma after the optional argument `#2` when `#2` is empty.

I tested `\IfNoValueF` and `\IfNoValueTF`. They work perfectly without `\newglossaryentry`, but they print "-No Value-" inside `\newglossaryentry`. ([I tired to follow this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/549813/skip-space-after-optional-argument)). How could I avoid printing "-No Value-"? Thanks!

Here's the what I did:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
            
%------------------------------
% GLOSSARY
%------------------------------
\usepackage[toc, section=subsection, nonumberlist, style=index]{glossaries}
\newglossary[bsc-log]{basic}{bsc}{list1}{Basic}
\makeglossaries

\usepackage{xparse}
%\basic{<name>}[<gender>]{<description>}[<other keywords>]
\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{m o m o}{
    \textbf{#1} 
    \IfNoValueF{#2}{\emph{#2}, }#3
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\basic}{m o m o}{
    \newglossaryentry{bsc:#1}{
        type=basic,
        name={#1},
        description={\IfNoValueF{#2}{\emph{#2}, }#3}, #4
    }
}

\begin{document}
% PRINT TOC
\tableofcontents

\newpage

\test{Primzahl}{prime number}

\test{Gleichung}[die]{equation}

\basic{Primzahl}{prime number}
\basic{Gleichung}[die]{equation}

%PRINT GLOSSARIES
\glsaddall
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also, this is my first time using the `glossaries` package. I'd like to know if there's any better solution to add genders of nouns? I tried to use `user1`, but it won't printout.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the string `-NoValue-` that's used for testing is “strange”, so it's not really normal text.

When you pass an `\IfNoValueF` test to `description`, it is essentially written “as is”.

A solution is to declare that the relevant fields should be expanded.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
            
%------------------------------
% GLOSSARY
%------------------------------
\usepackage[toc, section=subsection, nonumberlist, style=index]{glossaries}
\newglossary[bsc-log]{basic}{bsc}{list1}{Basic}
\makeglossaries

\glssetexpandfield{desc}
\glssetexpandfield{descplural}

\usepackage{xparse}
%\basic{<name>}[<gender>]{<description>}[<other keywords>]
\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{m o m o}{%
    \textbf{#1}%
    \IfNoValueF{#2}{ \emph{#2},} #3%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\basic}{m o m o}{%
    \newglossaryentry{bsc:#1}{
        type=basic,
        name={#1},
        description={\IfNoValueF{#2}{\emph{#2}, }#3\IfValueT{#4}{, #4}},
    }%
}

\begin{document}
% PRINT TOC
\tableofcontents

\newpage

\test{Primzahl}{prime number}[test]

\test{Gleichung}[die]{equation}

\basic{Primzahl}{prime number}
\basic{Gleichung}[die]{equation}

%PRINT GLOSSARIES
\glsaddall
\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After four hours, I fixed the problem by changing `o` to `O{ }` and changing `\IfNoValueF` to `\ifthenelse`

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\basic}{m O{ } m o}{
    \newglossaryentry{bsc:#1}{
        type=basic,
        name={#1},
        description={\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{ }}{}{\emph{#2}, }#3}, 
        #4
    }
}
```

Here's the result
[image]